# Need help on remainder factor theorem question.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials

Source--(https://brilliant.org/wiki/remainder-factor-theorem/)

Question--In an attempt to discover a formula for the Fibonacci numbers, Alex finds a cubic polynomial $h(x)$ such that $h(1)=1$, $h(2)=1$, $h(3)=2$ and $h(4)=3$. What is the value of $h(5)$?

answer by brilliant.org--
Consider the cubic polynomial $j(x)=h(x)−x+1$. Then $j(1) = 1$, $j(2) = 0, j(3) = 0$ and $j(4)=0$. By the remainder factor theorem, we have

$j(x)=A(x) (x-2)(x-3)(x-4),$

where A(x) is a polynomial. Since j(x) is a cubic, it follows that A(x) has degree 0 and thus is a constant which we denote by A. Substituting x=1, we obtain

$1 = j(1) = A(1-2)(1-3)(1-4)$ implies $A = -1/6$

Thus, $h(x) = j(x)+x-1 = -1/6 (x-2)(x-3)(x-4)+x-1$. Hence,

$h(5)=−1/6(5−2)(5−3)(5−4)+5−1=3$

Note: The closed form of the Fibonacci sequence is an exponential function. This cannot be approximated using a polynomial function for large values of n.

my doubt- how $j(x)=h(x)-x+1$  and what is $-x+1$ here? Please explain this in details . I am new in this topic . Thats why I need help.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: It's just another polynomial. By the factor theorem, you know that if a polynomial $q(x)$ takes value $0$ at $a$, then you can write $q(x)=(x-a)r(x)$ for some $r(x)$. But if you know that $q(a)=7$, say, you can't say much. They are doing a "shift" so that the polynomial will now be $0$ at $2$, $3$, and $4$: they notice that the value at $2$ is $2-1$, the value at $3$ is $3-1$, and the value at $4$ is $4-1$, so if they subtract $x-1$, they get a polynomial that is $0$ at $2$, $3$, and $4$.

Comment: P.S. Please use MathJax.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange.  I think [tag:polynomials] would be a better tag for this question

Comment: This isn't number theory. it isn't elementary number theory, and it most definitely isn't algebraic number theory. It is also not linear algebra. If you don't know what the tags mean, and you can't be bothered to read their definitions, then don't use them. Mistagging a question almost guarantees the right people will never see it.

Answer (score 2):

The purpose of choosing $j(x)=h(x)-x+1$ is so that for the values of $j(2,3,4)$ will result in equaling zero so that it is possible to factorise $j(x)$.

To recontextualise this question to see what I mean, say we change the question so that the cubic $h(x)$ instead gives $h(2)=-5, h(3)=-7, h(4)=-9$. Since you want $j(2,3,4)=0$ this time you would consider $j(x)=h(x)+2x+1$. Then you would follow the same steps as the *brilliant.org* answer.

Comment: but how you get 2x+1 in j(x)=h(x)+2x+1

Comment: @ABIDB11152 We see it is going up by odd numbers so you make an educated guess really.

Answer (score 1):

Forget $h(x)$.... just forget it.  (for now).

Suppose we ask an entirely *different* question:

How do we find a cubic polynomial $j(x)$ so $j(1) = 1$ but $2,3,4$ are the three roots of $j(x)$?

Well as $x = 2, 3,4$ are the three roots of $j(x)$ we can use the remainder theorem to find that $j(x) = A(x) (x-2)(x-3)(x-4)$ but as we want $j(x)$ to be a cubic we have $A(x)$ is just a constant we can call $A$.  And as $j(1) = A(1-2)(1-3)(1-4) = 1$ we find $A = -\frac 16$ and $j(x) = -\frac 16(x-2)(x-3)(x-4)$.

That gives use a cubic polynomial $j(x)$ where $j(1) =1; j(2)=0;j(3)=0; j(4) = 0$.

But we didn't *want* that!

We wanted a cubic polynomial $h(x)$ where $h(x)=1; h(2)=1;h(3)=2; h(4)=3$.

How do we find *that*?

Well notice that $D(x) = h(x) - j(x)$ is a polynomial so that

$D(1) = h(1) - j(1) =1-1 = 0; D(2)=h(2)-j(2)=1-0=1;D(3)=h(3) - j(3)= 2-0=2$ and $D(4) = h(4)-j(4) = 3-0 =3$.

So what polynomial has

$\begin{cases}D(1)= 0\\D(2)=1\\D(3)=2\\D(4)=3\end{cases}$

?

It's easy to see that is just a linear progression and is the polynomial $D(x) = x-1$.

So $h(x) - j(x) = D(x) = x-1$ so

$j(x) = h(x) -x+1$.  And $h(x) = j(x)+x -1$.

And we had $j(x) = -\frac 16(x-2)(x-3)(x-4)$ and we have $h(x) = j(x) + x -1$ so

$h(x) = -\frac 16(x-2)(x-3)(x-4) + x-1$.

And that's that.  That is the cubic polynomial where $h(1)=1; h(2)=1; h(3)=2; h(4)=4$.

And $h(5)=-\frac 16(5-2)(5-3)(5-4) + 5-1 = -\frac 16\cdot 3\cdot 2\cdot 1 + 4=-1 + 4 =3$

=====

In general if we want to find a polynomial where $h(w_1)=c_1; h(w_2)=c_2; ..... h(w_k)=c_k$ a strategy is to use the remainder theorem to find a polynomial $j_1(x)$ where $j_1(w_1) = c_1$ but $j_1(w_i) = 0$ for all other $w_i$.

The we can reduce the question to finding a polynomial $D_1(x) = h(x) - j_1(x)$ where $D_1(w_1) = 0$ and $D_1(w_i) = c_i$ for all the other $w_i$.  That might not seem any easier, but notice we did reduce the number of non-zero values by $1$ and if we reiterate we will eventually find a $D_k(x)$ where $D_k(w_{1...,k-1}) = 0$ and $D_k(w_k) = c_k$ and we can find *that* with the remainder theorem and the putting it all together we will have found $h(x)$.